# Creating clustered bar chart using Aspose.Words

Tags: java, aspose.words

Is there any way to draw clustered bar chart in word document using Aspose.Words in java?
Please find the below image for clustered bar chart.

[image: Clustered bar chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DocumentBuilder.insertChart](https://reference.aspose.com/words/java/com.aspose.words/documentbuilder#insertChart(int,double,double)) method to create chart using Aspose.Words. Also see Aspose.Words documentation to learn more about [creating charts](https://docs.aspose.com/words/java/working-with-charts/).
In your case you should use ChartType.BAR.

```java
Document doc = new Document();
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);

Shape chartShape = builder.insertChart(ChartType.BAR, 200, 300);

// Chart is created with default data
// here you can modify the chart data
// .....

doc.save("C:\\Temp\\out.docx");
```